# Warning about needs of SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM despite app doesn't schedule any alarm

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play, android-r8

I have seen this warning in google play console:

> Your use of exact alarms is causing your app to crash for some Android
> users Your app schedules exact alarms without checking whether the
> SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission has been granted. This is causing your
> app to crash for users on Android 14 because the permission is no
> longer granted by default.
>
> In most cases, alternative methods of scheduling work or inexact
> alarms are more appropriate. If your use of exact alarms is justified,
> update your app so that it checks this permission is granted before
> scheduling.

My app doesn't have any alarm scheduling feature of any kind, so this depends on some android, google or firebase module that merges code that has `android.app.AlarmManager.setExact(...)` somewhere for some reason.
But I have no idea what is the library that introduced it.

Is there any way to make Gradle/R8 building process to output the library that merged it and eventually prevent to merge the problematic code?

Comment: Have similar problem, update all libraries and the same

Comment: Any solution to this found? WorkManager can be the root cause of the issue ?

Comment: You can use [Apktool](https://apktool.org/) to decompile you app to smali (`apktool d --no-res app.apk`) and then grep in all `.smali` files for the method reference.

Comment: The message disappeared, could it be some kind of error in the console or testing?

Comment: Are you still seeing this Alert ?

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm scheduling an INEXACT alarm according to the documentation, so not sure where this is coming from. Thank you